# I changed my display manger to lightdm but appearence didnt change.(ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: lightdm

I followed https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-cinnamon-desktop-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux
and changed my display manger but no change in appearence

Comment: Can you choose your display manager at the login screen?

Comment: no ,there is no option to choose display manger in login screen